# 2d curve to 3d surface that does not depend on the 3rd coordinate

Tags: plotting

How can I make the following procedure?

make a surface from a 2d curve that does not depend on the 3rd coordinate?

I will give here an example for the procedure I'm trying to make:

(1) Making a list out of the 2d curve using `ContourPlot`:

```
pp = ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
Cases[Normal@pp, Line[pts_, ___] :> pts, Infinity]
points = Partition[Flatten[%], 2]
```

[image]

(2) Adding by hand the z coordinate (here I cant manage to do it well):

```
pc = Table[
  Table[{points[[All, 1]][[i]], points[[All, 2]][[i]], j}, {i, 1, 
    Length[points[[All, 1]]]}], {j, -1, 1, 0.1}]
```

(3) Plotting the 3d surface:

I should get something like this

[image]

Can anyone advise about how to make this procedure well? I'm doing it this way since I'm extracting a nullcline solution of a very complicated function using contour plot. If there anyone has a more efficient way, please write so as well.

Comment: Now I'm confused. You have a 2d equation and you are using `ContourPlot` to find a specific contour, right? You basically showed how you can extract a 3d surface: Just use `ContourPlot3D`

Comment: @halirutan, as I mentioned at the end of the question, I geve this as an example of what I'm trying to do. I use contour plot to get the nullcline sloution of a highly nonlinear function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long for a comment, but I seem to be missing the point here. So you have a highly non-linear equation that you can plot with `ContourPlot`.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
expr = Sum[
   Product[Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {2}]], {i, j}]/
    Product[Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {2}]], {i, j}], {j, 1, 
    2}];
```

Now we can do the normal plot

```
ContourPlot[expr == 2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we like to extrude this to 3D, we can introduce an artificial z coordinate

```
ContourPlot3D[expr == 2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit

If you are concerned with the runtime, then I can assure you that you can make it almost as fast as the usual contour plot. You just need to specify the plot points appropriately because we don't need any resolution in z-direction. Here is a more complex example with an expression that is two pages long:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
expr = Sum[
   Product[Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {2}]], {i, j}]/
    Product[Norm[{x, y} - RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {2}]], {i, j}], {j, 1, 
    10}];
ContourPlot3D[expr == 15, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
 PlotPoints -> {50, 50, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: that works out well, and is simple.

Answer (score 3):

One way to answer your question is to interpolate in z-direction between the curves f0[x] and f1[x]

```
f0=Interpolation[Map[{#[[1]], {#[[1]], #[[2]], 0}} &, points],InterpolationOrder -> 1]
f1=Interpolation[Map[{#[[1]], {#[[1]], #[[2]], 1}} &, points],InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

Interpolation gives

```
ParametricPlot3D[Interpolation[{{1, f1[x]}, {0, f0[x]}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][z], {x, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

In this way the extrusion could  be realized between two different curves too...

Comment: This procedure works, but it is extremely slow, is there any way to make it perform better?

Comment: See my edited answer. Now the plot is created in 0.13s, hope it's fast enough ;-)